# How can I log to a specific file in linux using logger command?

Tags: bash, logging

I will run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
./myprogram

#get exit code
exitvalue=$?

#log exit code value to /var/log/messages
logger -s "exit code of my program is " $exitvalue
```

But I don't want log message to be written in `/var/log/messages` because I don't have root privileges. Instead I want it to be written to a file in my home directory: `/home/myuser/mylog`

How should I modify `logger` command above?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you really need to (or want to) involve `logger`/`syslog` for this. Simply replace the last line of the script with:

```
echo "Exit code of my program is $exitvalue" >> /some/file/that/you/can/write/to
```

Comment: Proper timestamping would be lost this way, he'd have to do it manually then. Also, to support priority levels and/or tags (which are very common features of even the most primitive loggers, e.g. differentiating success, error, warning etc.), he'd have to implement, that, too from scratch. 
(Been there, done that, and after a few halfhearted attempt I just ended up with logger, too.)

Comment: @Sz. Those observations are all correct. But, aside from customizing the configuration of `syslog` (or `syslog-ng` or `rsyslog`, whatever version his distribution is using), which he can't do without root privilege, rolling your own, possibly with the aid of certain Python/Java/whatever libraries are available, is pretty much the only way to get the logs into a file that you control...

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use `logger` so that the message appears both in the system logs and in some file of yours, you might do

```
  logger -s your message 2> $HOME/somefile
```

since the `-s` option to `logger` also outputs on *stderr* which is redirected to the file with `2>`

You could want to use `2>> $HOME/somefile` to append (not overwrite) your `$HOME/somefile` (read about [`bash` redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)), and (see [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) for details) you may prefer to pass the program option `--id=$$` to `logger`.

Comment: How about exitvalue=$? ? where should i insert it above?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I use this command, it shows on STDOUT. But it didn't save in the givwn file . Why ?

Comment: `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout. It will not write to a file unless you redirect stdout to this file too. You can redirect both with `> the_file 2>&1` or, if you don't want to save stdout, you can do `2> the_file`. I'll edit the answer with the latter.

Comment: This works great for me:
logger --no-act -s LOG MESSAGE HERE >> test.log 2>&1

Comment: You might want to use 2>> to make sure you do append to the log file. The version with the single > will empty the log file

Comment: @Kieveli thanks so much, i was looking for such feature. works great! this way logs won't be duplicated in system

Answer (score 9):

The short "official" answer is that, unfortunately, you can't.

However, in most cases (e.g. on many Linux distros) you may just be lucky enough to have a `logger` implementation that both supports the `--no-act` option, and also implements some message formatting on its own (see below), in which case you can use a (moderately ugly) command like this to put a) a properly formatted message, b) to a file, c) not polluting the system logs:

```
logger --no-act -s "Oh dear..." 2>&1 | sed 's/^<[0-9]\+>//' >> /tmp/my.log
```

*(Shout out to @BasileStarynkevitch, and @Kieveli, who both mentioned parts of it before, just not the whole story.)*

**Notes:**

1) To match the usual log file format, I had to "sed off" the `<PRIVAL>` field (`PRIVAL` = `FACILITY` * 8 + `PRIORITY`) that got prepended to the output on my Debian boxes. Your mileage may vary.

2) POSIX itself does *not* define how exactly the `logger` command should treat (any of) its options. E.g. the [GNU logger](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/logger-invocation.html) does not support `--no-act` at all.
Also, when posting the original version of this answer 2 years ago, `-s` on my system did *not* do any formatting to the printed output, it just echoed the raw message alone, rendering it completely useless. (I didn't use Systemd at that time, which might explain the difference, seeing various conditional Systemd-related calls in the logger source code, but this is just vague guesswork.)

3) The most likely reason why the `logger` command has been so "historically unfriendly" for this trivial use case is that it's just a fairly simple frontend to the system logger. This means that anything you feed to it basically goes right through to `syslogd` (or `systemd-journald` etc.), which, in turn, does all sorts of other further processing, and dispatching (to various outlets: files, sockets etc., both local and remote), as well as bridging permission levels (so in your example you could still log to `syslog` or `user.log`, for instance, even though you may have no permission to write to those files directly).

For `logger` to be able to properly log to a file directly, it would either have to (re)implement some of the duties of the system logger, and the `syslog()` std. library function, or it would be not much more capable than a trivial echo one-liner (less complex, perhaps, even than the above `logger` invocation! ;) ). Either way, that seems like a bad idea.

A better solution could be if the POSIX interface ([logger](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/logger.html), [syslog()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html)) had a way to specify an ad-hoc outlet/facility parameter (like a filename) along with the message, so one could log to custom files without reconfiguring the system (which normal users have no permission to do anyway).

However, for the lack of anything better, the "canonical" Linux `logger` [implementation](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) actually does seem to duplicate some of the syslog functionality, so most of us can just enjoy that luxury for free. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think your better choice would be to use the `date` command rather then `logger` in cases where you don't want to write to the syslog files (and don't have privs to do so).

See "[timestamp before an echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88661/timestamp-before-an-echo)" for details on how to use `date` to prefix a message with a date and write it to a file.

You create a bash function that looks like the following, adjusting the `date` format string to get what you want:

```
echo_time() {
    echo `date +'%b %e %R '` "$@"
}
```

In your bash script, you would then use:

```
echo_time "Your message here" >> ${LOGFILE}
```

Which would put the following in your `${LOGFILE}` file:

```
Mar 11 08:40 your message here
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ man logger
```

> Logger provides a shell command interface to the syslog(3) system log module.

You'll need to change your syslog configuration if you want it to log things to other places. You could establish a certain *facility* that has an output file in your home directory, for example. You would need to be root to do that, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small logger function like this on top of your script file:

```
#! /bin/bash

#LOG FILE location
log_file=/tmp/mylogfile.log

#the LOG function
LOG()
{
time=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
echo "$time"" >>> "$1 >>${log_file}
}


message= echo "test logger message"
#to send loggers to your log file use
LOG "my message logged to my log file with timestamp = ""$message"
```

check output :

```
head -1 /tmp/mylogfile.log
2019-09-16 14:17:46 >>> my message logged to my log file with timestamp = test logger message
```

Answer (score 0):

I you can use `cat -` witch echoes your output then `>> [file]` witch prints the output to `[file]` inset of terminal so the command would be

```
cat - >> [file]
```

the down side is you have to use ctrl+C or ctrl+Z to exit `logger` is better for online code