# Write to custom log file from a Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, logging

In Linux, I know how to write a simply message to the `/var/log/messages` file, in a simple shell script I created:

```
#!/bin/bash
logger "have fun!"
```

I want to stop throwing messages into the default `/var/log/messages` file, and create my own.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
logger "have more fun" > /var/log/mycustomlog
```

It still logs to `/var/log/messages`.  It did create the `/var/log/mycustomlog`, but it's empty.

Anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: can't you simply replace *logger* with *echo* ?

Comment: I don't think you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423303/how-can-i-log-to-a-specific-file-in-linux-using-logger-command

Comment: Redirecting standard output doesn't work because `logger` doesn't write to standard output; it writes to the file configured by `syslog(3)` to receive log messages.

Comment: This makes more sense now.  I'll post what I did....

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`logger` logs to syslog facilities. If you want the message to go to a particular file you have to modify the syslog configuration accordingly. You could add a line like this:

```
local7.*   -/var/log/mycustomlog
```

and restart syslog. Then you can log like this:

```
logger -p local7.info "information message"
logger -p local7.err "error message"
```

and the messages will appear in the desired logfile with the correct log level.

Without making changes to the syslog configuration you could use `logger` like this:

```
logger -s "foo bar" 2>> /var/log/mycustomlog
```

Specifying `-s` or `--stderr` instructs `logger` to print the message to STDERR as well (in addition to logging it to syslog), so you could redirect STDERR to a file. However, it would be utterly pointless, because the message is already logged via syslog anyway (with the default priority `user.notice`). Note that we use here `2>>` to append standard error to the file named.

Comment: For anyone else who was confused at the use of the number 2 after the string in the last example, 1 redirects stdout, and 2 redirects stderr. More info available here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: And for anyone who doesn't know how to edit the syslog configuration, here it is on Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/42152/where-is-syslog-conf

Comment: What does the `-` before the file path indicate? I've tried googling around but can't find anything about it. Is it required?

Comment: @Wimateeka It explicitly disables syncing for that particular log file. See [`rsyslog.conf` manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html#ACTIONS).

Answer (score 39):

@chepner make a good point that `logger` is dedicated to logging messages.

I do need to mention that @Thomas Haratyk simply inquired why I didn't simply use `echo`.

At the time, I didn't know about echo, as I'm learning `shell-scripting`, but he was right.

My simple solution is now this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This logs to where I want, but using echo" > /var/log/mycustomlog
```

The example above will overwrite the file after the >

So, I can append to that file with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I will just append to my custom log file" >> /var/log/customlog
```

Thanks guys!

- on a side note, it's simply my personal preference to keep my personal logs in `/var/log/`, but I'm sure there are other good ideas out there.  And since I didn't create a daemon, `/var/log/` probably isn't the best place for my custom log file. (just saying)

Comment: `/var/log` is absolutely the best place for virtually any kind of log.

Comment: I agree that this is a good approach but the log file will keep growing and there is no mechanism of archiving or deleting old logs. If you log frequently, then this can take considerable amount of storage.

Answer (score 7):

There's good amount of detail on logging for shell scripts via global varaibles of shell. We can emulate the similar kind of logging in shell script: http://www.cubicrace.com/2016/03/efficient-logging-mechnism-in-shell.html
The post has details on introdducing log levels like INFO , DEBUG, ERROR. Tracing details like script entry, script exit, function entry, function exit.

Sample Log:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you see the man page of logger:

```
$ man logger
```

> LOGGER(1) BSD General Commands Manual LOGGER(1)
>
> NAME logger — a shell command interface to the syslog(3) system log
>   module
>
> SYNOPSIS logger [-isd] [-f file] [-p pri] [-t tag] [-u socket]
>   [message ...]
>
> DESCRIPTION Logger makes entries in the system log. It provides a
>   shell command interface to the syslog(3) system log module.

It Clearly says that it will log to system log. If you want to log to file, you can use ">>" to redirect to log file.

Comment: This is an incorrect interpretation of the man page.  `logger` uses `syslog` or (in the case of most Linux systems) `rsyslog` which can be configured to place log messages where ever you like.

Answer (score 2):

I did it by using a filter.  Most linux systems use rsyslog these days.  The config files are located at `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d`.

Whenever I run the command `logger -t SRI some message`, I want "some message" to only show up in `/var/log/sri.log`.

To do this I added the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/00-sri.conf` with the following content.

```
# Filter all messages whose tag starts with SRI
# Note that 'isequal, "SRI:"' or 'isequal "SRI"' will not work.
#
:syslogtag, startswith, "SRI" /var/log/sri.log

# The stop command prevents this message from getting processed any further.
# Thus the message will not show up in /var/log/messages.
#
& stop
```

Then restart the rsyslogd service:

```
systemctl restart rsyslog.service
```

Here is a shell session showing the results:

```
[root@rpm-server html]# logger -t SRI Hello World!
[root@rpm-server html]# cat /var/log/sri.log
Jun  5 10:33:01 rpm-server SRI[11785]: Hello World!
[root@rpm-server html]#
[root@rpm-server html]# # see that nothing shows up in /var/log/messages
[root@rpm-server html]# tail -10 /var/log/messages | grep SRI
[root@rpm-server html]#
```

Comment: Rather than `:syslogtag, startswith`, consider `:programname, isequal`. Ref https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/properties.html